# Issues running ant.cmd in windows, "/*? unrecognized

Tags: java, ant

Facing this issue for the first time and been running around it for sometime now.

Wile running ant.cmd am getting the following error

```
C:\>ant.cmd

C:\>/*
'/*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
'Licensed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
'contributor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
'this' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
'The' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
you was unexpected at this time.       

C:\>   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with

C:\>
```

1. Tried making the file as ANSI encoding still same error
2. All the setting of environment variable is correct.
3. User ant1.7, ant1.8.2 and now ant1.9.2, same issues in all the version

Any thoughts?

Comment: whats the value of path variable that you have set up? çan you goto the bin dir of ant installation in command prompt and than run ant

Comment: hm... looks like a java comment block and I doubt that the batch can process that. Can you show us the content of the ant.cmd file an what it does?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to run `ant.cmd`, that script is for OS/2, not Windows.

You should run `ant.bat`. Or just `ant`, if the bin\ directory of ant is in your PATH` You might find more info [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)